# Iterating through List of Strings C#

Tags: c#, list

I need to build a string by iterating through list of strings

my input is a  `List<string>` and below are 3 sample cases of possible input:

```
case 1        case2      case3
  5             5          ""
  +             +          +
  6             6          6
  +             +          +
  9             9          9
  -             -          -
  8             ""         8
  +             +          +
  1             1          1
```

The desired resulting output for each of the above sample cases should be as follows (each of which is a single string value):

Case1 : `"5+6+9-8+1"`

Case2 : `"5+6+9+1"`  (as the value after 9 is "" it shouldn't be considered and the preceding operator should also be ignored)

Case3 : `"6+9-8+1"`  (as first value is "" it shouldn't be considered it and following operator should also be ignored)

Comment: Is that 3 lists containing 9 characters each?

Comment: Substituting `0` for `''` would be easier. And you did mean `""` (empty string), right?

Comment: You want the sum of all these numbers?

Comment: Do you only use + and - or do you want / and * too?

Comment: @Purplegoldfish: It doesn't make any difference what operators they want to use, same code to get it done

Comment: @musefan actually it does if a) he wants this sum to be correct or b) his next question is how to do the calculation. 1 + (2 * 3) is different to (1 + 2) * 3 etc

Comment: I'm also wondering if they are actually interested in calculating the result, in which case it might make sense to split the operands and operators onto different stacks to prepare for PostFix processing.

Comment: Can't understand the votes up here where we struggle to understand what the OP wants exactly.

Comment: @Otiel: The OP is quite clear and provides a 'normal' sample and 2 edge cases. The confusion comes from idle speculation about what to do next with the strings .

Answer (score 4):

I am making the assumption that every other string in the input list is an operator. Then you can do this...

```
//from another function
string[] inputList = new string[] { "5", "+", "6", "+", "9", "-", "8", "+", "1" };
string result = JoinList(inputList);

//function to join list
public string JoinList(string[] inputList){
    if(inputList.Length == 0)
        return "";

    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    int start = 0;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputList[0]))
        start = 2;

    for (int i = start; i < inputList.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = inputList[i];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (list.Count > 0)
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
            continue;
        }

        list.Add(s);
    }

    return string.Join("", list);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding (= You have a `List<String>` as input and you want a `String` as output):

```
List<String> str = new List<String> {"5", "+", "6", "+", "9", "-", "", "+", "1"};
String case1 = "";
str.ForEach(x => case1 += x);
case1 = Regex.Replace(case1, @"(?<![0-9])(\+|-)", "");
```

Will give you: `case1 = "5+6+9+1"`